# Sqlite Replication Using Redis

Tags: redis

Am very new to redis tool.
My goal is to replicate 2 Sqlite databases(master/slave concept).
Is it possible using Redis tool? 
If so can anyone please guide how to do it.

Comment: Here the Databases will be remotely located. so is it possible to replicate the data for remote machines .

Comment: Redis is not a database replication tool. While you can implement distributed queues with Redis, it is probably not suited for master/slave database replication, which requires ordered and guaranteed delivery of data (once and only once semantic).

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in this [hack](https://github.com/grisha/thredis/commit/2beaee3a13f0dbe0c161470da04ef8af21d78fc9):

> with this patch [...] a SQLite DB is entirely stored in a Redis Hash object.
>
> A very neat side-effect of this little hack is that it lets a SQLite database be automatically replicated using Redis replication.

You can found more details within this blog post: http://grisha.org/blog/2013/05/29/sqlite-db-stored-in-a-redis-hash (the core idea is to use Redis as a backend for sqlite thanks to the VFS interface).

Comment: hey the hack mentioned is for older version! has anyone tried out this and replicate sqlite database??